# WordPress posts in a different language

Tags: wordpress, unicode

i have a website in WordPress and i want to type the posts directly in "Gujarati" language. i know that i cannot type directly, so first i type it in MS word and then i copy and paste the content in the website...but when i paste it, it doesn't show the correct language (it shows some symbolic fonts)... so i got to know from somewhere that the posts are typed in Unicode fonts only

so for unicode fonts.. google translate/google tool kit can be used.. now i am able to copy and paste in the post. but now when i hit publish/update the post, the content is not shown in the website.

i have attached the links... please view

first link shows the dashboard where i have pasted the content(in unicode).. and the second one is the place where you can read the post in the website 
so can anybody help me with this?
please correct me if i am wrong somewhere or please give me suggestions or may be alternate method to do this?...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7UzpxMCUs7JeHRYa014dGZuQzg/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7UzpxMCUs7JcEgyOWFMWndUTHM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, it looks as if your permalinks have been screwed up in the process with the post names unicode characters. You are safest to go change the permalink structure to the default.

`wp-admin --> settings --> permalinks --> default`

Comment: You don't need to thank me :-) Just accept answers if they helped to show your appreciation. Welcome to StackOverflow.